# make command doesn't produce any executable

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

My `Makefile` contains the following:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall

main: hello.o hello_fn.o

clean:
   rm -f main hello.o hello_fn.o
```

It should have produced an executable file `main` (I've read that in Introduction to GCC by Brian Gough), but actually it haven't.

The output should be like this:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -c -o hello.o main.c
gcc -Wall -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
gcc hello.o hello_fn.o -o main
```

But actually it's like this:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
```

When I type `$ make` again, it says that `'main' is up to date`.

Comment: Change `main` to `hello` and see if that works. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#index-linking_002c-predefined-rule-for ("It will also do the right thing if there are multiple object files (presumably coming from various other source files), one of which has a name matching that of the executable file.")

Comment: I'm just gonna guess... GCC _knows_ how to make `.o` files from `.c` files that are named the same. How show GCC _know_ you want it to compile `main.c` outputting to `hello.o`? If you want to use the built in smarts of GCC, then you have to play be the rules...

Comment: @9769953 changing `main` to `hello` doesn't solve the problem. Maybe I'll have to update `make` or something?

Comment: Could you show the line(s) you have changed in your Makefile?

Comment: @9769953 I simply changed all `main` to `hello`

Comment: The [built in rule you're trying to use](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-linking_002c-predefined-rule-for) won't work here because the target name `main` doesn't match any of the object file names.  Change `main: hello.o hello_fn.o` to `hello: hello.o hello_fn.o` and you should get an executable named `hello`.

Comment: Check what version of you make you have: `make --version`.

Comment: @9769953 `GNU Make 4.3`

Comment: Did you change `main.c` to `hello.c`? Alternatively, replace `hello.o` by `main.o` (and change the main target back to `main`). The basename parts should match: you can't expect an automatic rule to compile `gcc -Wall -c -o hello.o main.c`, going from main to hello; which is what the expectation in your question is.

Comment: @9769953 I've done everything you told me, but still nothing.

Comment: Could you provide an update to your question with the latest Makefile you have?

Comment: You apparently think that, based on some hidden tricks, make knows that to produce `hello.o` it must compile `main.c`, while to produce `hello_fn.o` it must compile `hello_fn.c`. Think at it: how could make possibly know this if you don't tell it?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  See where you went wrong:

```
$ cat Makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

hello: hello.o hello_fn.o

clean:
        rm -f hello hello.o hello_fn.o

$ cat hello.c
int main() { return 0; }

$ cat hello_fn.c
/* empty */

$ make
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
gcc   hello.o hello_fn.o   -o hello
```